# How to unit test the universal link?

Tags: unit-testing, ios-universal-links

Since I need to write unit tests for our project, does anyone do this before?
How to test the universal link by codes?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to open a Universal Link programmatically. Apple only allows Universal Links to be opened with user intention. That means calling `openURL:` will open the link in Safari.

I would suggest mimicking the same response to a Universal Link by programmatically calling `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:`. This is the function called by universal links and can be triggered programmatically. You'll just have to ensure that the passed off user activity has all of the same information that your universal links activity would have. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found a really cool example how to do this here:

https://blog.branch.io/ui-testing-universal-links-in-xcode-9/

Basically it opens the iMessage app in the simulator, sends a message containing the link to one of the simulator's contacts, then taps on the link within the message app.

You can then assert whether your app was opened or if the correct view was opened depending on what you want your universal link to do within your app.

Comment: When I try this in an iOS 14 simulator, the link seems to disappear immediately after I send it. Am I doing it wrong, or have things changed with iOS 14?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XCUITest to test full interaction: open Safari; load page with your link; tap on link; ensure your App is opened; ensure your App is handled Universal Link properly. This is not an easy setup. And generally driving Apps you not control (like Safari) is not a documented feature of XCUITest.
Can use this https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent as a reference. It does uses XCUITest under the hood.